# Solving Project Euler #2 in Python

Tags: python

I am attempting to do Project Euler problem #2. Which is:

> Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two
>   terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...
>
> By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed
>   four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

However the terminal window hangs when I use the following code with 4000000. Smaller numbers run ok. Is there something about this code that is really inefficient, hence the lagginess?

```
n = int(raw_input("Enter the start number: "))

def fib_generator():
    a, b = 0, 1
    yield 0
    while True:
        a, b = b, a + b
        yield a

def even_sum(fib_seq):
    seq = []
    seq = [next(fib_seq) for number in range(n)]
    seq = [number for number in seq if number % 2 == 0]
    return sum(seq)

def start():
    fib = fib_generator()
    even_sum = even_sum(fib)
    print even_sum

start()
```

Comment: Solve the problem on paper first, for a few small numbers. Compare the results with those from your code.

Comment: Also, I would change both `seq = [...]` lines to `seq = (...)` (or use `ifilter` and `takewhile` from `itertools`). That will create generators and avoid having to ever store the entire list at once in memory, which will make it slower for large input values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bug. You're generating the first 4,000,000 Fibonacci numbers, but the problem statement only asks for those Fibonacci numbers whose *values* are not more than 4,000,000.

Since the Fibonacci numbers grow exponentially (F<sub>n</sub> ~ 1.618<sup>n</sup>), you're generating some numbers with a very large number of digits (log<sub>10</sub> F<sub>n</sub> ~ n / 5) and that will take an immense amount of time.

Fix the bug, and you'll be okay.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add logic to stop when the next fibonacci number exceeds 4000000.

Also, I spy a potential problem with this line:

```
def start():
    fib = fib_generator()
    even_sum = even_sum(fib) #<--- right here
    print even_sum
```

It isn't good to have a variable name the same as the function name.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is something inefficient in your code, you load a very long list into memory twice, with your two `seq = ...` statements. Why not try one generator expression rather than two list comprehensions? Also, you could alter your Fibonacci generator to stop at a certain number:

```
def fib_generator(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

def even_sum(fib_seq):
    seq = (number for number in fib_seq if not number % 2)
    return sum(seq)

def start():
    n = int(raw_input('Enter max constraint: '))
    fib_seq = fib_generator(n)
    even_sum1 = even_sum(fib_seq)
    print even_sum1

start()
```

Answer (score 0):

This ran pretty fast for me

```
lst = []
num1 = 1
num2 = 2
sum = 0
jump = 0
next = 0

while next<4000000:
    next = num1 + num2
    if next<4000000:
        if jump ==0:
            num1 = next
            jump = 1
        else:
            num2 = next
            jump = 0
        if next%2 == 0:
            lst.append(next)

for item in lst:
    sum+=item

print ''
print "Sum: ",
print sum
```